# How to combine a Silhouette-4.0.X UserAwareAction with Cache Action?

Tags: caching, playframework-2.5, silhouette

I'm trying to combine UserAwareAction with Cache. I'm able to get CacheBeforeSilhouette but not the other way around? Could anyone give me a hint on how to do this?

```
@Singleton
class MessageController @Inject() (
  implicit val env: Environment[DefaultEnv],
  silhouette: Silhouette[DefaultEnv],
  cache: CacheApi,
  cached: play.api.cache.Cached)
    extends Controller with I18nSupport {

...

  def testOnlySilhouette = silhouette.UserAwareAction { request =>
    Ok("hi")
  }
  def testOnlyCache = cached("homePage") {
    Action {
      Ok("Hello world")
    }
  }
  def testCacheOfSilhouette = cached("homePage") {
    silhouette.UserAwareAction { request =>
      Ok("hi")
    }
  }
  def testSilhouetteOfCache =
    silhouette.UserAwareAction { request =>
      cached("homePage") {
        val res:Result = Ok("hi")
        res //type mismatch; found : play.api.mvc.Result required: play.api.mvc.EssentialAction
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Christian Kaps @akkie replied on gitter:

The problem is first that the play.api.cache.Cached.applyfunction returns a CachedBuilderwhich needs an EssentialAction as parameter. So you must always write:

```
Cached("some-key") {
  Action {
    Ok("")
  }
}
```

The second problem ist that the request types are not compatible. The Play classes needs a Request[B] but Silhouette produces a SecuredRequest[E, B]. With a bit handwork you can get it to work:

```
def testSilhouetteOfCache = 
  silhouette.SecuredAction.async { securedRequest =>
    cached("some-key") {
      Action {
        Ok("")
      }
    }.apply(securedRequest.request).run()
  }
```

You need a implicit val materializer: Materializer injected